# Dynamic Names When Exporting in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, script

Is there a way to dynamically use the document name in export?

For instance, I have artboards named `Square`, `Horizontal`, and `Vertical`, in a document named `Design`. When exporting, I'd like filenames to be `Design %ArtboardName%`. Or, is there a way to mass change artboard names?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic naming while exporting might be a little complicated: I believe you'll need to create the whole exporter as a script this way. However mass change artboards names is super easy with scripting. For example this one will change all artboards of the document to `DocumentName ArtBoardName`

```
var docName = activeDocument.name.replace(/\.[^.]+$/g, ""); // getting the active document name without an extension
var i;

//for each top-level layer set (an artboard or a group)
for (i = 0; i < activeDocument.layerSets.length; i++) {
    //rename it to docName layerSetName
    activeDocument.layerSets[i].name = docName + " " + activeDocument.layerSets[i].name;
}
```